# How to generate rsa-sha2-512 using terraform for azure vm

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Below terraform code is working fine for Redhat 7 but when I choose redhat 9, unable to login using ssh key.

How to generate rsa-sha2-512 key using terraform so that it can used in vm creation and login using private key.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
}

#https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
provider "azurerm" {
  features {} 
  client_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

#create resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name     = "${var.prefix}${var.envprefix}${var.productname}"
    location = "${var.location}"
    tags      = {
        Environment = "dev"
    }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
    name     = "Default-Networking"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "xxxxxxx"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name}"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "xxxxxxx"
  virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "nicazew${var.envprefix}${var.productname}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "tls_private_key" "linux_key" {
    algorithm = "RSA"
    rsa_bits = 4096
}

resource "local_file" "linuxkey" {
    filename = "xxxxxxx.pem"
    content = tls_private_key.linux_key.private_key_pem
    }

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                = "vmazew${var.envprefix}${var.productname}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "xxxxxx"
  source_image_id     = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/xxxxx/images/azure_redhat_9_baseos"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic.id,
  ]
  
  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "xxxxxx"
    public_key = tls_private_key.linux_key.public_key_openssh
  }


  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic,
    tls_private_key.linux_key
  ]  
}
```

From above code below components used for generating ssh public and private key and used in vm, Need help on how to generate rsa-sha2-512 and use in vm.

```
resource "tls_private_key" "linux_key" {
    algorithm = "RSA"
    rsa_bits = 4096
}

resource "local_file" "linuxkey" {
    filename = "xxxxxxx.pem"
    content = tls_private_key.linux_key.private_key_pem
    }

# used in vm creation block

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "xxxxxx"
    public_key = tls_private_key.linux_key.public_key_openssh
  }
```

Getting bellow error while logging.

[image]

Comment: [**The `ssh-rsa` key doesn't change only the algorithm(s)**](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) but you need PuTTY 0.77 or higher. Alternatively your host is offering ecdsa-p256 and ed25519 keys and PuTTY 0.68 or higher can handle those. (0.80 is current, as of a few weeks ago.)

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085, now I am able to connect to vm using latest PuTTY(080). thanks you so much for  help.